# xarray select 24 hours from 01 to 00 inclusive

Tags: python-xarray

I have an xarray whose time dimension begins at hour 01, then 02, 03, ..., 23, 00, 01, 02, ... 23, 00, ... and so on. For each hour I have a value. That value is an accumulation of the previous hour, so, for example, value at 01 is the variable from 00 to 01.

I want to resample summing to have values per day, that is, sum from 01, 02, ... to 00, and again 01, 02, ..., 00, but I can't grok it. If my xarray is for instance

```
da = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(0, 119, num=120), coords=[pd.date_range("15/12/1999",\\
                  periods=120, freq=pd.DateOffset(hours=1),)],dims="time")
```

I have tried both `da.resample(time="24H").sum()` and `da.resample(time="24H", closed="right").sum()`, but none of them seem to do exactly what I want. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake, indeed what it works is using:

```
da.resample(time="24H", closed="right", label="right").sum()
```

(adding label to clarify a little bit more).